# How to add space between cells' borders in Mac Pages (without removing the borders)? See image attached

Tags: pages

I would like to create a table that looks like this:

[image]

Is that even possible in Pages?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do what you want. You could make each cell a new 1x1 table and space then apart. But this takes a while and is difficult to work with. I was able to make tables that looks like the images below. Not what you wanted but similar I think. The spacing can be increased on these tables.

[image: s]

[image]